# Getting position number from an array

Tags: php

If I have the following array in session, can I get a item position number in each [cat]:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [cat] => 1
            [que] => Description here.
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [cat] => 1
            [que] => Description here.
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [cat] => 1
            [que] => Description here.
        )
)
```

For example the following will give me the second description, but how do I get that it has position #2 (out of 3) in [cat] == 1:

```
$item = $_SESSION['questions'][2]->que;
```

The actual array is much larger and has more than 1 [cat]. The count I am trying to get is withing each such group.

Comment: What is *position* ? the `id` or the array index ?

Comment: You're right, sorry, the numeric value is actually of the ID.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you're looking for a more native way, but worse case scenario, you could add another element to hold the index value.

Comment: The items in array can be omitted dynamically, so i do not want to tie it to any value stored in the table.

Comment: I don't know if PHP supports such an option but you might be able to do a manual process... could you loop the array w/ a counter?

pseudo c# code to illustrate what I'm thinking:

int index = 0;
foreach (object row in array)
{
  if (row == this) then break;
  index++;
}
return index;

Answer (score 0):

By adding a dummy entry at the beginning of the array:

```
array_unshift($_SESSION['questions'], array());
$item = $_SESSION['questions'][2]->que;
```

Comment: Although i'd say this is bad practice (allocating space for nothing)

Answer (score 0):

```
    foreach($_SESSION['questions'] as $key=>$val)
    {
      if($val->id == 3)
      echo $key;
    }

//or

    foreach($_SESSION['questions'] as $key=>$val)
    {
      if($val->que == "Description here.")
      echo $key;
    }

//do what ever you want
```

Comment: if you have a dynamic content, if you know the item you looking for. cat, or id, or you are searching que text. use it to compare. please, get more clear senario or example, i am glad to explain more to you.